# jQuery memory performance using addClass() vs css().

Tags: jquery, performance

I have a grid layout of divs, that when the cursor moves over the div it changes color.  I have to use jQuery so I am using the mouseenter function.  I can use either

`$('#someId').addClass('someClass');` or `$('#someId').css('background', 'red');`

I found information about speed performance between the two http://jsperf.com/jquery-css-vs-addclass-speed/2 but which method is better for memory performance if any, especially if you have 10,000 plus divs.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Memory performance is of such little concern compared to good separation of concerns. As such, you should ***always*** use `addClass()` and specify those classes in an external stylesheet. Also, you really shouldn't be having 10,000 divs in a single page. Use paging or some other pattern to reduce it.

Comment: Hadn't your link provide an answer?

Comment: I know there are better ways of doing this.  The exercise wanted you to use jQuery and divs.  Also, wanted do know at what point did the number of divs start creating a lag in the responsiveness of the program, if any.  I did not see any speed difference so I wondered if there may be any issues with memory performance.  I see know that the addClass would not be the issue just creating so many divs would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There won't be much difference in performance, since you manipulate the object using an ID in both cases, which makes the main difference. The action you choose does not really matter then. Still adding a class gives you the possibility to just change the class and to easily remove it at a later point.